# Exponentiation of real numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, real-numbers

If $x>0$ is a real number such that $x^\alpha<1$ for some real number $\alpha$.

Then $x<1$?

Thank you.

Comment: What is $2^{-1}$?

Comment: and if $\alpha>0$?

Comment: Sorry but i could not understand **"then" $x<1$** part... Do you want to say $0<x<1$?

Comment: yes $0<x<1$...-

Comment: Well then ... i guess you know .... $x^{-n} = \dfrac{1}{x^n}$

Comment: If $ 0 < a <1 $ and $ 0 < b < 1 $ then multiplying both sides of $ 0 < a <1 $ gives us $ 0 < ab < b $, but $ 0 < b < 1 $ therefore $ 0 < ab < b  < 1 \Rightarrow 0<ab<1$, now replace $a, b$ by $x$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a is a real number then you can make $x^a$ as small or as large as you like my making a more and more negative or more and more positive, regardless of the value of x. consider:

1)If x is between zero and one, then you can make your number a largely positive to get a number that is very close to zero and positive, thus between zero and one.

2)If x is between zero and one, then you can make your number a largely negative to get a number that is largely positive.

3)If x is a number greater than one, then you can make your number a largely positive to get a number that is also largely positive.

4)If x is a number less than one, then you can make your number a largely negative to get a number that is also negative.

This means that not knowing anything about a, other than it is real, knowing that x is positive and knowing the value of $x^a$, there is no way of calculating the value of x.

You will note that I have not mentioned what happens when x is a negative number. This is not important for pre-calculus, but if mathematics is something that you find fun then it might be something worth thinking about. See if you can work it out.(This requires an understanding of complex numbers)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you'll find this board useful:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline\\
&y<0&y=0&y>0\\
\hline\\
0<x<1&x^y>1&x^y=1&0<x^y<1\\
\hline\\
x=1&x^y=1&x^y=1&x^y=1\\
\hline\\
x>1&0<x^y<1&x^y=1&x^y>1\\
\hline
\end{array}$$